# the same image is sometimes rotated 180 degrees sometimes

Tags: filepicker.io

I am using filepicker.io to upload an image from iOS device to Filepicker.

In my code, I am using image tag ">. When I view the image:
1) on a desktop browser (Chrome) it's upside down (rotated 180 degrees) 
2) I view the same HTML page from my mobile device (iOS) and it's the right way up.
3) If I just view the filepicker.io link (I not via imag tag) in a browser it's the right way up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed some browsers ignore the EXIF orientation info.  This mostly affects IOS devices.  I've worked around this by transforming images right after they are uploaded:

```
filepicker.convert(InkBlob, 
     {width: 800, format: 'jpg', quality: 85, rotate: "exif"}...
```

Comment: Thanks. Was trying to see if I could workit out client side. I ended up using http://www.graphicsmagick.org and doing it server side with .autoOrient() which is pretty much the same as using filepicker convert option. Thanks again.

Comment: We were doing that for a while too, but since we are letting filepicker write to an S3 bucket, it's more efficient to let them do it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's the "orientation" and I guess some browsers seem to auto-apply/fix this. The short of it is, I need to find out what the orientation is and then apply/rotate the image accordingly.

I have managed to do this manually with JavaScript loadImage.

I am trying to work out how to do it dynamically in this thread [Can't get EXIF info using loadImage.parseMetaData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982771/cant-get-exif-info-using-loadimage-parsemetadata) I have an idea of what to do, it's just not working... but I'll leave that to be sorted out in that thread.